# Is there an idiom that can be used to describe the specialty of a situation/object?

Tags: idiom-requests

For instance,

> the <*best part*> of living alone is the privacy.

Is there an idiom which can be used for such a sentence?

I'm looking for a rather well-known phrase originating from literature, like how 'Achilles' heel' is used to describe a fatal flaw.

Comment: "Best part" is an idiom. And rather well-known, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about the well-known idiom **silver lining**?

> M-W:  a consoling or hopeful prospect

> Cambridge: an advantage that comes from a difficult or unpleasant situation

> The Free Dictionary:  a consoling aspect of a difficult situation

Your example:

> The **silver lining** of living alone is the privacy.